# How to generate convex polygon

Tags: algorithm, math, polygon, computational-geometry, centroid

I really can't think of any method which would be efficient and faster. Does anyone has any clue?

Comment: To make sure I understand the problem: you are given a point (x, y), an integer k > 2, and a side length l.  You want to construct a regular k-gon whose centroid is at (x, y) and whose sides are of length l.  Is this correct?

Comment: Your problem, as stated, is under-constrained.  So, are you looking for a specific n-gon with particular characteristics, or will any one do?  If you're looking for something a little more specific, you will need to better articulate your requirements.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

make a circle around the centroid and inscribe the n-gon in that circle.

Comment: Hi, I want an irregular convex polygon, whose centroid and number of vertices are provided, which means I have only (x,y), which is the centroid and n as the number of vertices of that convex polygon.So, making circle and inscribing the n-gon would only produce regular convex polygon, but I want irregular convex polygon.

Comment: @Cassie Jones:  All you're doing is saying what you **don't** want.  You need to edit the question to explain what you **do** want.  Otherwise, you're going to get answers such as this, which aren't helpful to you.